# How can Django's ContentType uniquely describe an installed model when it only stores the last part of the App's import path in app_label?

Tags: django, django-contenttypes

The docs state that three fields (app_label, model, name) [uniquely identify an installed model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType), while only storing the last part of the model's import path in app_label. How is this possible when you can have two models with the same name in different packages which happen to share the last module name, like:

1) coke.auth.User

2) pepsi.auth.User

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter: when you put `'auth'` inside `INSTALLED_APPS`, only one Django app could be imported, it could be `auth` from either `coke` or `pepsi`, or other place containing `auth`, depending on their first occurring in `sys.path`.

Also, in DB, the unique constraint is applied to `(app_label, model)`, the name is for description.

Comment: A correction, you put the fully qualified name ('coke.auth') in INSTALLED_APPS, but the app name (the last part) must be unique. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps